# How to emit the dropdown value to parent component while using BaseDropdown component

Tags: vue.js, events, components, bootstrap-vue

I have a BaseDropdown component which uses bootstrap-vue dropdown. Here is the code for the BaseDropdown.vue ( child component )

BaseDropdown.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
      <b-dropdown :text="text">
          <b-dropdown-item v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" @click="text = option.name;$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
          </b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "base-dropdown",
    props: {
        text: {
          type: String,
          default() {
            return {};
          },
        },
        options: {
          type: [Array, Object],
          default() {
            return {};
          },
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I want to get the currently populated dropdown-item value in the parent component

ParentComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <form class="auth-form">
    <BaseDropdown 
        :text="phaseType"
         type="input"
        :options="phaseTypeOptions">
      <h6 class="ml-4">PHASE TYPE</h6>
    </BaseDropdown>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import BaseDropdown from "@/components/Base/BaseDropdown";
  export default {
    name: "parent-component",
    data() {
      return {
        phaseType: "Single",
        phaseTypeOptions: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Single",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Three",
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    components: {
      BaseDropdown,
    }
 }
</script>
```

The "phaseType" in parent component is not updated when the dropdown value is changed ( initially it is single. When I change to three) its not updating in parent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be capture the value returned from the $emit event in the parent component.  Make the following changes:

In BaseDropdown component change the b-dropdown-item to be:

```
<b-dropdown-item
    v-for="option in options"
    :key="option.id"
    @click="$emit('input', option.name)"
  >
```

Then in your parent component you will need to change the BaseDropdown and the h6 tag to be the following:

```
<BaseDropdown
    :text="phaseType"
    v-on:input="handleInput"
    :options="phaseTypeOptions"
  >
    <h6 class="ml-4">{{ phaseType }}</h6>
  </BaseDropdown>
```

The v-on:input will be triggered from the $emit in the BaseDropdown component. It will call the handleInput method.  Add a methods object to be the following:

```
methods: {
handleInput(val) {
  this.phaseType = val;
},
```

},

With these changes when you make a selection from the BaseDropdown, the value will reflect the item selected by the user.